# How to incorporate an Android Application Project onto a Java Project - Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, selenium, robotium

I am a beginner with Java and Eclipse. I am trying to create an automated framework with both Selenium (Web application) and Robotium (Android Application). I have both project completed, one is a Java Project (Selenium) that uses the JDK compiler to run Junit test cases, and the other one is an Android Test Project that uses the Android Compiler to run android test cases.

My questions is: is there a way to combine an Android project onto a Java project?

I have tried adding the essential files/changes of an android project onto the java project but when I run each test it fails because it uses different compilers.

Is there a way around this? I am open to any suggestions.

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve by combining them as by the sound of it they are testing completely different things. If that is the case I would strongly suggest keeping them as separate projects otherwise you are going to run into lots of issues/limit what you can and cant do in both. If however you are using selenium to test web parts on the phone and using robotium on the phone then maybe i can help.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My purpose is to create a single automation framework project with multiple platform support (web, android apps, and iphone apps). I have been able to create an automation framework for each platform but I don't want the user to include different projects to test with. Selenium is used for a non-phone browser while Robotium is used for native-android apps. So is there really no other option than to just keep them as a separate project?

Comment: Keep them separate, you will save yourself a world of pain. Robotium relies on classes that are just on android your selenium will rely on classes not available to android and iphone is likely to be in a completely different language to the other two. What benefits do you actually foresee in being able to have them all in the same project? I believe any you see will be limited. What you could do is make another project to contain any common functionality and have the separate ones use that. That is your only real option.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your comment I believe i can say that you should keep them separate. If you want to share some functionality between them all (I cannot imagine you could share all that much between all 3, between android and selenium maybe as they are at least in the same language) then you can create another project and use this as a shared source folder between the two. You will find having them separate makes a lot more sense. The most glaring example is with version controlling your tests, you will find you will want to make tags when you release the actual application, with a single project you will be tagging your individual project for any release of any of the three applications when they will not reflect the actual state of release. That hopefully makes sense. I am pretty tired.